# Getting data from label with Selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I export the table with the ID "Grdhizmetkontrol" on the website to Excel with this code.

My point of improvement:
When I query with TC, the page that opens is this table that comes with the "grdHizmetControl" ID, there are lines with red font. I want to print these red rows in the table to the columns next to the TC I'm querying.

The code for the lines written in red in the right click elements “Inspect” listeners is `<tr style="color:Red;">` in this way, and the subtitles are written in the narration “td”.

I cannot share an address because web accesses can be accessed via external closed internet.

```vb
Sub vericek()
Dim baglan As New Selenium.WebDriver
Dim tablo As TableElement
Dim lastRow As Long
baglan.Start "chrome"
baglan.Get "http://deneme.aspx"
baglan.FindElementById("login-username").SendKeys "123"
baglan.FindElementById("login-password").SendKeys "123"
baglan.FindElementById("login-btn").Click

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastRow
    baglan.FindElementById("txtSicilTCNO").SendKeys Cells(i, 1).Value
    baglan.FindElementById("btnSicilTCNO").Click

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Set tablo = baglan.FindElementById("grdHizmetKontrol").AsTable
    Set Rows = tablo.FindElementsByTag("tr")
    For j = 0 To Rows.Count - 1
        Set Cells = Rows(j).FindElementsByTag("td")
        For k = 0 To Cells.Count - 1
            If InStr(Cells(k).Attribute("style"), "color:Red;") > 0 Then
                i = Sheets("Sayfa1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Sheets("Sayfa1").Cells(i, "B").Value = Cells(k).text
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
    baglan.FindElementById("txtSicilTCNO").Clear

Next i
```

I want to find the rows with red font color in the "grdHizmetKontrol" table. Then, I want to print the data from the found row(s) next to the queried Turkish ID number.

Comment: "The red color of the rows is written in the review section as `<tr style=”color:Red;”>`. I apologize as my English is not very good, I may not have expressed myself clearly."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example of how you could find the red row inside a an HTML table:

```vb
Sub FindRedRowInTable()

    Dim baglan As New Selenium.WebDriver
    baglan.Start "chrome"
    'Here I'm using Itty Bitty to render the html. More info here : about.bitty.site
    baglan.Get "https://itty.bitty.site/#/data:text/html;charset=utf-8;format=gz,eJxtkUGKAjEQRfd9itAXcK9tQBp0YHDjDcpUqWGSlFSqQT2NZ/FkRhpFnazyw0+9/6l0CttAxuO83Qv++Esk/eWkwqG1TdPcrrdrp2JHNd4Otud4hHTuJkV/O0nBadUZCvZ9psgnuESYrOdA89ZxYJluCGfti9Ap2kXYCWE2y0GV5M9npQLAjxS0axAPZpGQJFfsFUkci2O1xNfznh6bMI4jifMQzJqd0mWIUGEvBZLz2bHpD5D2tXJ08o7/h5fj8Qv2Dkghoas="
    'Because Itty Bitty put the html code that we need inside an iframe, we need to switch to that iframe, but that is probably not needed for your use case.
    baglan.SwitchToFrame baglan.FindElementByCss("[id='iframe']")
        
    Dim tablo As WebElement
    Set tablo = baglan.FindElementById("grdHizmetKontrol")

    Dim myRows As WebElements
    Set myRows = tablo.FindElementsByTag("tr")
    
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To myRows.Count
    
        Dim rowStyle As String
        rowStyle = myRows(j).Attribute("style")
        'Let's remove spaces and make it lowercase to avoid comparison issues with equivalent styles
        rowStyle = Replace(LCase(rowStyle), " ", "")
        
        If rowStyle = "color:red;" Then
            'Do what you need to do with the row here
            Debug.Print "Found the red row: " & j
        End If
        
    Next j

    'Closing the connection
    baglan.Close
    Set baglan = Nothing
    
End Sub
```